# Thermodynamics - Unsteady flow energy equation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, work, volume

can anybody explain what happened to the PV term in (dE/dt) for the control volume (system). It is mentioned that changes in kinetic and potential energy is neglected and so dE/dt = du/dt, if change in K.E & P.E were to be ignored then dE/dt should be equal to dh/dt, right?

[image: General Energy Equation]

[image: Unsteady Flow]

Answer (score 0):

> can anybody explain what happened to the PV term in (dE/dt) for the
> control volume (system)

If by "PV term" you mean $pdV$, or boundary work, it does not apply to open systems where the boundaries are generally considered fixed. $PV$ work is then $Vdp$ work, or flow work. Flow work, along with internal energy, are included in the enthalpy term ($h=u+pv$)

> if change in K.E & P.E were to be ignored then dE/dt should be equal
> to dh/dt, right?

Right since $h=u+pv$.  But when the KE and PE terms are ignored, $dE/dt$ becomes $dU/dt$ since the KE and PE terms apply to the energy of the  flow as a whole, and not the internal molecular kinetic an potential energy which applies to the components of the internal energy, $U$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the derivation of the open-system (flow) version of the 1st Law of Thermodynamics, the work done by the system is subdivided into two parts:  1. the shaft work W and 2. the work to force fluid into and out of the control volume.  The Pv work associated with the latter is lumped into the enthalpy terms on the left hand side of the overall energy balance equation.  There is no such term for the right hand side of the equation to lump in with dE/dt.  In fact, wishin the control volume P and v are often not even spatially uniform.

Comment: What i understood was that there is no PV in RHS because our energy analysis is for the control volume and since KE & PE were manifested within the fluid as a result of motion whereas PV work (Pressure energy) done is due to pressure difference across the control volume, Hence PV is not considered as energy that is associated with fluid flow inside the control volume but rather this work or energy goes in as changing the internal energy of fluid which is being accumulated in control volume. Hence dE/dt is approximated as dU/dt ignoring Q, Wcv, KE & PE. To conclude dH/dt (LHS) = dU/dt (RHS).

Comment: Sorry, I got RHS and LHS switched.  I have made the change in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for RHS only. dE/dt is approximately equal to dU/dt, Hence the total energy balance equation becomes dH/dt=dU/dt. Please read my previous comment and correct if anything is wrong.

Comment: It is dU/dt, not dH/dt.  This follows from the correct derivation of the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics.  You need to review it.